# Issue with VS2017 project not working when installed by Setup

Tags: visual-studio-2017, wix, setup-deployment

I have a very weird issue with a program I'm developing. The program works just fine and if the Release file of the project is copy/pasted, even compressed on .zip there is no issue. Fo far so good.

The problem comes when I try to create a Setup for this program. For some reason the setup itself works fine and there's no problems with the installation itself but the installed copy of the program doesn't work. It looks like it's trying to, but something doesn't goes the way it's intended and ends withour even showing the first window.

The add-ons I've tried to create the setup are WIX and Windows Installation Tools, both for VS2017; neither works. The application itself uses GMail API, GoAuth2 and Sqlite tech embedded in the code and the program file.

Comment: Did you check the installation directory? Compare with the outputDirectory of your releasee which is working fine, it might be that there are some missing dlls.

Comment: Yes I did. It added the dll without problems, but had to add the additional files required manually in the setup, like the "token.json" or the credentials. Both directories are perfect copies of each other.